# Should a controller be immutable?

Tags: java

I already know what is immutable and how it works, but most of all the theory applies for objects.

Is it worth to have an immutable controller?

what if my controller is like this

```
public class MyController {

    private MyService myService;

    public void doSomething(){
       myService.something();
    }

    public void setMyservice(final MyService myservice){
       this.myservice = myservice
    }
}
```

Supposing MyService is "immutable" , is it worth to make my controller "immutable" by removint the setter and only initializing it by a constructor?

Could someone give me a reason why I should have it on that way?

Comment: That parameter doesn't need to be final, by the way

Comment: What sort of controller? That can matter a good bit. The answer is "often yes", but frameworks differ somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is worth making your Spring beans immutable and you should do it.

[Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) contain a few reasons why:

> The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it enables one to implement application components as immutable objects and to ensure that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore constructor-injected components are always returned to client (calling) code in a fully initialized state.